# Unable to install mysql-Workbench (E: Unable to locate package mysql-workbench-community-8.0.17-src.tar.gz )

Tags: debian, workbench

this could be a very easy one but I am very noob in Debian.
I am trying to install workbench, I had many troubles to install mysql server and now I cant install workbench.

1.- It doesn't appear in the software repository (the one that is like a store)
2.- I downloaded the .deb and install like this :
    shell> sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.5.3-1_all.deb
    shell> sudo apt-get update
after that I downloaded the tar ant tried to install it like this inside the downloads folder: 
        sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench-community-8.0.17-src.tar.gz

and this: 
         sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench-community

and this happens :
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-workbench-community-8.0.17-src.tar.gz
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'mysql-workbench-community-8.0.17-src.tar.gz'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'mysql-workbench-community-8.0.17-src.tar.gz'

I have tried to install it for some hours using methods in video or the guide in MySQL and Still I can't..

Comment: Try   tar xvzf mysql-workbench-community-8.0.17-src.tar.gz, after go into the directory and install it.

Comment: I unpackaged the tar and get into the directory with CD, now, whats the command to install it, how can I search for the installer or built insete the folder? i tried this: sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench-community and the unable location came again, also I tried sudo apt-get install and nothing.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your directory?

Comment: yes this is my screen https://ibb.co/Htv24v8    and    https://ibb.co/kMkcbNK

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/  Follow this link, download the software,  and tape dpkg - i name_of_file. It's more simpler

Comment: Sorry for be that dummy on Linux but, in the page there isn't any debian software, thera are for linux, fedora and generic linux, the generic linux is the same .tar.gz I hav already downloaded before, the other two option of linux and fedora are .rpm and the other a .deb, wich one should I download? I have already these : https://ibb.co/RbYzn7K

Comment: Select Linux Ubuntu 18.04 64 bits.

Comment: :/ I lack of some stuff https://ibb.co/GW5j0rN

Comment: OK, you need to satisfy all dependencies. So type apt-get install - f

Comment: I did it, and the following happened: https://ibb.co/r6Q4BJZ  , then I tried the installation and the same error for dependencies appeared : https://ibb.co/6nfz7mM

Comment: Try to install all missing dependencies  like libzip5, libssh-4

Comment: I made it dude :) thanks a lot, I install them using the manager aptitude and workbech is running, the bad think is an advertisement about thet is the ubuntu and not the debian version but I need it to learn an collage things so its not gonna be a problem , thanks everything.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with Snap

```
   sudo snap install mysql-workbench-community
```